# Giving feedback on the design

Tags: discussion, design

Thanks to Mat and Jin the new design is live. Here's how to report bugs. If you find a problem with the design that is *CSS related*, for example something doesn't line up right or look wrong, then Jin will handle these problems.

If it's a *design* related issue, like you feel something about the look needs work, etc., then Mat will look at it.

Please tag all feedback with a **bug** and **design** tag.

Comment: it is looking gorgeous!

Comment: @JorgeCastro Done

Comment: I don't know if this is an illusion, but it feels like I have zoomed in the pages on this site. The fontsize is HUGE.

Comment: (tounge-in-cheek) Crtl - Minus ?? :) (How do you do the this-is-a-key-on-the-keyboard thing??)

Comment: I found this after asking [my question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/539/1273), but I tagged [feature-request] rather than [bug] because it's more of a wishlist item.  Others may have done the same, especially if they're used to meta.SO, so be sure to watch that tag too.

Comment: Design is just a copy of orginal ubuntu site :-P. Think something original.. refer this link http://www.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 15):

Why is the header so huge?  It takes up way too much retail space and offers little to no value.
[image]

Compare it to the amount of space used by Stack Overflow or any of the other sites, and this seems outrageously tall.

Comment: Agree. As I commented before, the site looks magnified, maybe because of this.

Comment: Yes! it's terrible for notebooks. I wonder why this hasn't been changed, part of the design for unity was to reduce wasted vertical screen space.

Answer (score 13):

The **Ask question** button is hard to see when you arrive on the site for the first time, I don't understand why it is not at the right of the orange panel.

The search entry is way too small, it should be much much bigger.

Comment: agreed. the ask button is too hidden. looks more like a simple label. it should be more "buttonized"

Comment: Yeah, this may be true, I found it only because I knew it had to be somewhere in that area..

Comment: Yes yes yes. Once you've spotted it, it's obvious, but it was a couple of seconds of "what am I, retarded?" when I was looking for it. Even just different colouring would have made it easier to spot.

Answer (score 6):

g's are chopped off in comments!

[image]

Comment: Not seeing that here.

Comment: @flute is is chopped off in Windows/Chrome at least

Comment: It's chopped in ubuntu/chrome also.

Comment: And Arch Linux/Chromium

Comment: See this gggggg

Comment: I don't know if this has changed since reported or if it's because I'm using a Chrome beta (7.0.517.36), but I don't see it on Chrome/Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't see it anymore either. Looks like fixed.

Comment: Its fixed for me too. I could see it before.

Comment: disregard, problem was with me, not the site

Answer (score 3):

Bug: The title of the site should be updated to "Ask Ubuntu". It still reads as "Ubuntu - Stack Exchange".

Answer (score 3):

I am not a designer. But honestly saying i dont like the design.

1. Tags are not visible.
2. Header is too long
3. It took me 10 seconds to identity where is "Ask question button", provided i am using stack overflow from more than 1 year with more than 350 visits.
4. This gray background is not good when you are reading consider these two examples. On [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823571/im-graduating-with-a-computer-science-degree-but-i-dont-feel-like-i-know-how-to) and on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6651/anyway-to-actually-make-10-10-a-10-10-closed). White is much better.
5. Why you guys are trying to make thinks look funky or stylish etc. Simple things are much better. Considering this editor i was confused where is the hyperlink button. This infinity kinda symbol sucks.(Please dont mind it but it sucks.)

I am sure you guys have very good designer. But i think design should be reconsidered and go for simple and sober. Making thinks stylish is good for a website like "Nike or Reebok."

Comment: Re #5: Stylish and simple aren't mutually exclusive. AskUbuntu is stylish, but it's also clean and simple. I find it much easier to look at and find the information I need than messier sites like the default StackOverflow.

Comment: I find the normal stack overflow layout with its less 'simple' elements a lot easier to use. They are way more obvious. Also, all those dotted backgrounds are really unfriendly to my eyes.

Comment: Actually in my point the small variation in colors making the design unfriendly to eyes. It should be one colored background with some basic highlighting (where necessary). I think thats why tags are not visible.

Answer (score 3):

I actually really like the site design but it doesn't work well in the small window I tend to keep stack exchange sites in while working.  I can only usually see about 3 questions on the main page.

So if anyone is interested, I created a [userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/38242) to reclaim a lot of the wasted vertical space.  Screenshots are available there (especially if you use [this style](http://userstyles.org/styles/6158)).  You can check the css to remove some optional bits if you just want to reduce the size of the header.  I'm welcome to feedback (probably best done on userstyles.org).

Comment: Nice, Awesome work.

Answer (score 0):

Both the design and the service are just awesome!
Good work ;)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know who Mat and Jin are, but this design is awesome!

Kudos guys and keep up the good work!