# Tone down "edited comment" icon

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, comments, icon

Compared to other SE sites I've participated in, especially SO, the icon for "this comment was edited" sticks out like a sore thumb on Ask Ubuntu.

Could it be toned down?

Here's my crude attempt, alongside the original, of an orange-ish outlined pencil; I've merely erased most of the orange and then lightened it a bit:

[image: modified] [image: original]

Comment: @roger, I agree it draws a bit more attention than needed. What do you think if the pencil icon is in orange, and the circle is just a 1px outline?

Comment: @Jin: That works for me!

Comment: I agree. It could have a little transparency, to keep the color.

Comment: @roger, a quick update: i still intend to change this, just been swamped lately.

Comment: @Jin: Thanks for the update; no rush as long I as know it's been seen. :)

Comment: @roger i updated the edit icon tonight, both for the main site and meta. the changes will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(moved from comments)*

> I agree it draws a bit more attention than needed. What do you think if the pencil icon is in orange, and the circle is just a 1px outline? – Jin Oct 18 at 7:53

> I updated the edit icon tonight, both for the main site and meta. The changes will be in the next deployment. – Jin Oct 30 at 2:42

The change is now live.