# Comment "edited" icon is too big...

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, icon

As you can see the circle outline is bigger than the space alloted for it, which causes it be "cut off".
[image]

Comment: That [damn edit icon](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/539/tone-down-edited-comment-icon) :P

Comment: i'll put in a fix for it soon..

Comment: (Also the same applies to the meta icon)

Comment: @Jin any updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about the delay. I have made the icon smaller and it is now on dev, will be in the next deployment. (This applies to both the parent and meta site)